# svnadmin load fails at particular revision no and deletes the commited directory

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svn-administraton

I'm trying to load dump of my svn repository which I have taken through

```
svnadmin dump repository > repository.dump
```

and I'm trying to load it by using command

```
svnadmin load repository < repository.dump
```

svnadmin load fails at particular revision no and deletes the committed directory

svn admin commit 1182 and start deleting at revision 1183 all committed directory.

[image: svn admin commit 1182 and start deleting at revision 1183 all committed directory]

Please suggest the methods to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

> svnadmin load fails at particular revision no and deletes the
>   committed directory

`svnadmin load` does *not* fail in your case. It successfully loads the dump to the new repository. What you see is that the revision 1183 removes some versioned items from [HEAD](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.keywords) revision 1183. You can always revert this action using svn client application. Read [SVNBook | Undoing Changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo).